# Is there any way to fire loadComplete event only first time when grid is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to fire JQgrid event "loadcomplete" only for the first time. I have found this code

```
var isPopulated = false;

...

function onLoadComplete(){
   if(!isPopulated){
      //your code here
      isPopulated = true;
   }
}
```

I know this code will work fine but i want this without any variable. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do u want to this without a variable?

Comment: I suppose that you misunderstand the goal of `loadComplete`. I suppose that you need to use some callback either before filling the grid or on the first load from the server (is you use `loadonce: true` for example). What exactly you want to do inside the callback?

Comment: @Akshay Because I need cleaner code.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for responding. loadonce is not true in my case, sorting and pagination is being handled on the server side. I want to call a function e.g searchGrid() on loadComplete, that function will filter the data and reload the grid, that's why I need searchGrid to be executed only the first time when grid is loaded.

Can we do this without using a flag/variable?

Comment: Why you need to load the grid first with unneeded data and then to reload  the same grid with correct data? **You can load the data with the filter directly at the beginning.** The code which you included in your question have no sense thus it's difficult to understand. I recommend you to include more reasonable code which more close to the code which you use. Having the code one can suggest you how it could be changed.

Comment: Exactly. You are right. It should be load data at the beginning.